# T-SQL How to update hour in a SmallDateTime column?

Tags: t-sql

let's say that I have a SmallDateTime column in my table. How to update hours in each row in T-SQL ?

Comment: from any value to any value (provided by the user in the stored procedure's parameter)

Comment: So you would want to look for all rows with `18:00` time component for example and update those to `19:00`?

Comment: or even e.g from 18:00 to 23:00

Answer (score 2):

1. Get the target value's hour part.
2. Find the difference between the hour you want and the found hour.
3. Add the difference of hours to the target value.

The script:

```
UPDATE atable
SET datetimevalue = DATEADD(hour, @hour - DATEPART(hour, datetimevalue),
                                  datetimevalue)
WHERE ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE YourTable SET YourDateColumn = DateAdd(hh, 1, YourDateColumn)
```

will add 1 hour to the time value in `YourDateColumn` in every single row.

See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258267%28SQL.80%29.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE YourTableName 
SET YourSmallDateTimeColumn = DATEADD(HH, 1, YourSmallDateTimeColumn)
```

Will add any number of hours to your column. So if you get rid of the time component first:

```
SELECT CAST(CONVERT(char(8), YourSmallDateTimeColumn, 112) AS smalldatetime)
```

and add hour component to it later it should work.

From [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/faq/dates-p03.aspx)

> To add or subtract hours to a datetime
>   or smalldatetime value, you will use
>   the DATEADD date function.  The
>   DATEADD date function returns a new
>   datetime value based on adding an
>   interval to the specified date.  The
>   syntax of the DATEADD date function is
>   as follows:
>
> ```
> DATEADD ( datepart , number, date )
> ```
>
> datepart is the parameter that
>   specifies on which part of the date to
>   return a new value.  For hours, you
>   can use either HOUR or HH.  number is
>   the value used to increment datepart. 
>   date is an expression that returns a
>   datetime or smalldatetime value, or a
>   character string in a date format.
>
> Here's an example on how to use the
>   DATEADD date function to increase or
>   decrease a datetime value by a certain
>   number of hours:
>
> ```
> SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, -12, GETDATE())AS [TwelveHoursAgo]
> SELECT DATEADD(HH, 6, GETDATE()) AS [SixHoursLater]
> ```